# Find a Particular Substring using Regex

Tags: string, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I am trying my hands on Email Services, am stuck at a place where I need to create a regex.

I want to find all substring which looks like "PIKA-170510-115943".

Here is my code.

```
String str='Strating text PIKA-170510-115943 Ending Text';
String regex='[A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}';


Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
Boolean result= matcher.find();

System.debug('result is : '+result);
if(result){
   System.debug('Matching string'+matcher.group(1));
}
```

The result is always true and when it enters the IF block it gives me .

> EXCEPTION: System.StringException: Group index out of bounds (parameter 1): No group 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches` matches the entire string against the Pattern (by default; you'll want to read more about Regions in the documentation). Instead, you'll want to use `find`:

```
Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
Boolean result= matcher.find();
```

To read the matched string, use the zeroth group:

```
System.debug('Matching String: '+matcher.group(0));
```

Comment: Now it enters the If block . But cant return the substring.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You need to use `group(0)`, because you haven't used any [capture groups](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_capturing_groups.htm).